# Im trying to programmatically insert a WebView into my Code

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view

I have a surfaceview with a click listener attached to it.

When i click it, it shrinks it to half the width and half the Height... and places it in the Lower Right Corner via:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(  
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2,
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2    
);
rlp.setMargins(
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2,    
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2, 
  0, 
  0);
```

It works as intended, but i want to place behind it Dynamically a webView.

I tried:

```
WebView wv = makeWebView();
//makeWebView(); is a method of my mainActivity, which simple does.
private Webview makeWebView(){ return new WebView(this); }
```

I cant seem to get it to be behind everything else though.  Am i doing something wrong?

my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RR1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.testfortim;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView();
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    sv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL1);
            //LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)ll.getLayoutParams();
            //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ll.getLayoutParams().width/2,ll.getLayoutParams().height/2);//(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)ll.getLayoutParams();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2, 
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2
                    );
            rlp.setMargins(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2, 0, 0);
            ll.setLayoutParams(rlp);

            WebView wv = makeWebView();
            //wv.setBackgroundColor(0);
            //wv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Blue);
            //wv.setBackgroundResource(Color.BLUE);
            wv.loadData("<html><body>TEST</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RR1);
            //rl.addView(wv);

            //ll.addView(wv);


        }

    });

}

protected WebView makeWebView() {
    return new WebView(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I resized the Linear Layout and moved that, so the Webview would need to be placed somewhere in RR1, from what i gather.   I was looking at various documentation, and it either wasnt quite what iw as looking for or MAYBE by randomness, i just didnt grasp it.

Do you have ideas as to how this is accomplished?

As a sidenote:  I have no idea why the onCreateOptionMenu method is there.  I dont plan on using it, and will prolly end up removing it.

Comment: why dont you try adding WebView in the xml instead of SurfaceView. There has to be an id that links your xml with java code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html  go through this

Comment: you can make everything in Android programmatically if you want to.  I should be able to add a childNode to the ParentNode no problem.  Am I right

Comment: yes but thats a bad approach. If you do everything programmatically, then you wont be able to support all screens. Hence divide put all UI related stuffs in XML and java code in your workspace.

Comment: I am aware It is smart to keep UI and backend separate but this example cannot do that.  I am not arguing that though.  I am just curious as to how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried  'rl.addView(wv, 0);'??

Comment: It works!   I guess add was pushing it outside the ViewPort, where as the 0, insides it into the 0th position.  I thank you Faizan

Comment: add is pushing it to the last index...not outside, man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `rl.addView(wv, 0);`
will do the trick :)