# Android take layout through code

Tags: android

I have an xml layout file in my layout folder in android.
And i want to refer to that file through code to add a webview.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Im trying to programmatically insert a WebView into my Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815027/im-trying-to-programmatically-insert-a-webview-into-my-code)

Comment: Would you make you question more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give an id to your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    id="@+id/layout" >

</LinearLayout>
```

and then you can get it:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

and you can now add your WebView to this layout.