# How do I Resize my WebView in Activity?

Tags: android, xml, webview

[image: My first Question in Avtivity]

[image: Second Question in same Activity]

[image: Same First Question But you can see my webView hight increased but not decrease in this question]

My XML File WebView

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/WvQue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Can Anybody tell me what is the problem I am Facing?

1st Image is my first question in activity
2nd Image is my second question in activity 
3rd  Image is my first question but it takes the hight of second Question How do I resize this ?

Comment: did you found the answer in the question below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is that you should look these two questions

[WebView doesn't resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311321/webview-doesnt-resize)

but from that i see you need to create new WebView every time

[WebView height = wrap_content with changing font size doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765059/webview-height-wrap-content-with-changing-font-size-doesnt-work)

And the answers too...

**EDIT** for creating new webview  programmatically

[Webview in programmatically created RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221777/webview-in-programmatically-created-relativelayout)

and this also [Im trying to programmatically insert a WebView into my Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815027/im-trying-to-programmatically-insert-a-webview-into-my-code)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot: I updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765059/webview-height-wrap-content-with-changing-font-size-doesnt-work/21140015#21140015 but creating a new WebView for each answer is probably a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

**You should create WebView in your code instead of updating it's content.
Follow the steps:**

1. Replace your WebView tag in your layout file with following:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/webViewContainer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. Do following in your Activity class code:

   ```
   if (webView!= null) {
    webViewContainer.removeAllViews();
    webView.destroy();
   }
   webView= new WebView(context);
   webViewContainer.addView(webView,
               new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                       FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, myHtmlString, "text/html",
                   "UTF-8", null);
   ```