# Changing the size of the webview after clicking on it

Tags: android, dynamic, webview

I want to dynamically create a `web view` and on click change the size of the webview to `fill_parent` and after on click again it should revert back to the previous dimensions i has custom set. I have been able to create a web view dynamically so far and tried passing new parameters on click but what happens is that webview covers the whole screen and does not revert to the previous size after the second click.

Any help is appreciated.

My current code looks similar to this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout layout;
    Boolean flag=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);

        TextView textDynamic = new TextView(this);
        textDynamic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textDynamic.setText("Hello Android");
        layout.addView(textDynamic); 


        final WebView web = new WebView(this);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    300, 100);
            webViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);


            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewNewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        web.loadData("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://myurl.com/test.php\"></script>", null, null);
//RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        //      300, 100);
    //  final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewNewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        layout.addView(web, webViewParams);
        web.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
            Log.e("test", "msg");
            layout.removeView(web);
            //web.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);


            if (flag=true)
            {
                flag=false;
                web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                layout.addView(web, webViewNewParams);

            }
            else
            {
                flag=true;
                web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
                web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
                //webViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                layout.addView(web, webViewParams);

            }
        //  web.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        //web.setLayoutParams(webViewNewParams);
            //web.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
        //web.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
            }
            return false;

        }
    }); 

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to resize a Web view in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246031/unable-to-resize-a-web-view-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code which is running properly...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout layout;
    boolean Expanded = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, 250);
        webViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewNewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        final WebView myBrowser = new WebView(this);

        myBrowser.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");

        layout.addView(myBrowser, webViewParams);
        myBrowser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (Expanded) {
                        myBrowser.setLayoutParams(webViewParams);
                        Expanded = false;
                    } else {
                        myBrowser.setLayoutParams(webViewNewParams);
                        Expanded = true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Your change does not work. nothing happens after clicking the view. It does not resize evev. Have you tested this yourself? I cant seem to pin point where I am going wrong.

Comment: yeah..I have tested myself.

Comment: it is not working for me. did you check it by replacing it with some other url like google or something?

Comment: you should clean your project then run it again.

Comment: Glad to hear it from you...Now, you should close the other question related this topic.

Comment: surely. I will do that.

Comment: I am closing this question. Accepted your answer on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

As per My research work Web view can not Resize . Means after Increase size of Web view you cannot decrease size again. [see this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136752/how-do-i-resize-my-webview-in-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here...
Change

```
if (flag=true) {
```

to

```
if (flag==true) {
```

and rest will work fine